# Generate new SSH Key in Git GUI

Tags: github, github-for-windows, git-gui

Actually, I have generated a SSH Key using Git GUI. But I would like to modify the existing SSH Key. I don't see any options for modifying the existing key.

Can anyone tell me how to modify the existing SSH Key?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To modify the existing default ssh key, you don't need to gui.

Make sure your `<git>\usr\bin` is in `%PATH%` and type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "key for xxx access" -q -P ""
```

That will propose to override your `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)` (with `%HOME%` generally set to `%USERPROFILE%`)